# What is the type of these signals?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, machine-learning, time-series

I want to do some DSP and Machine learning experiments on Electrical and Acoustic signals, but, due to some language setbacks, I didn't know how to call the type of my signal, what I use to google now, is "Time series". Is there a more precise "key word" "terms" that may put me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you give more details about your signals? How they are recorded, sampled? What they look like? "Time series" is fairly  generic, esp. outside signal processing; "discrete signal", "discrete sequence", "discrete-time signal", "digital signal", "data frame" are options with slightly different meaning, but in the same field

Comment: There was a modest repository of recorded signals at Rice when Don Johnson was IEEE Signal Processing President, which is gone but the mirrored archive is http://spib.linse.ufsc.br/index.html.

Comment: Thanks, Laurent Duval, my topic is electrical machines diagnosis, the current subject of interest is Partial Discharge, signals are acquired using Sensors (Hall effect, Acoustic sensors ...) ... what i really want to do, is applying machine learning algorithms, to help in localizing defects, and making prediction, so, when I google around, there are tons and tons of information, but most of them aren't related directly to my subject

Answer (score 4):

Types of signals:

- According to their **range set (values)**: *Real Valued, Complex valued* ;
- According to their **dimensions**: *Scalar, Vector* ;
- According to their **values**: *Continuous Amplitude, Quantized* ;
- According to their **domain set (arguments)**: *Continuous-time, Discrete-time* :
- According to their **mappings**: *Deterministic, Stochastic (Random)* ;
- According to their **character**: *Periodic, Even, Odd, Symmetric...* ;

A Time-Series is another name given to a discrete-time random sequence which is an instance of some discrete time random process. As it's a random signal, the sequence samples do not have a mathematical formula which connects the points to each other along the series, hence it's viewed as a series of numbers which were generated according to some probabilistic law.

Consider the following: You generate a continuous-time deterministic signal $x(t)$ by exciting an oscillator which produces a periodic sine wave of exactly known frequency, phase and amplitude. Then sample this signal to produce a discrete-time sequence $x[n]$. The point is that by just observing the sampled signal you cannot tell whether the sequence of samples actually belong to a deterministic signal with a mathematical formula that can be used to generate all of its samples, or they belong to a random process whose values happen to be fitting into the observed sine wave (which has a very small probability (improbable) but is not impossible otherwsie). Hence any such sequence can be considered as a random sequence of numbers denoted as a time-series.

After a certain amount of analysis you may conclude that the observed sequence of numbers probably belong to a deterministic sine wave of certain frequency,phase and amplitude. But this deduction is only an estimation. The truth cannot be known but precise predictions can be computed.

Comment: Very interesting explanation of the schochastic character of time series, I haden't thought about it this way... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There apparently exists an R package for the clustering of "Partial Discharge" data: [pdCluster: Partial Discharges Clustering](http://pdcluster.r-forge.r-project.org/).

> Partial discharge measurements analysis may determine the existence of
>   defects. This package provides several tools for feature generation,
>   exploratory graphical analysis, clustering and variable importance
>   quantification for partial discharge signals.

This could be a starting point. In the following description, I put in bold the concept of "damped exponentials" or "damped sinusoids", that could describe the morphology of your data. This is an instance of non-stationary data.

> A clean partial discharge signal can be regarded as **a finite
>   combination of damped complex exponentials**. Under this assumption,
>   the so-called Prony's method allows for the estimation of frequency,
>   amplitude, phase and damping components of the signal.

The recent paper [New clustering techniques based on current peak value, charge and energy calculations for separation of partial discharge sources](https://doi.org/10.1109/TDEI.2016.006352), 2017, may provide other key references.